# IP address for updates

Tags: command-line, apt, ip-address

Our security groups are pretty locked down by IP address. I've been asked to try to find the IP address that any updates would come from so we can create a security group for it. I can't seem to find that info anywhere. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu provides updates via the `<codename>-updates` channel e.g. for `trusty` (`14.04`) that would be `trusty-updates` (URL e.g. `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates`). Any other non-official repository should also follow this norm.

So, searching in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` to get the domain names of the `updates` repositories, and using `dig` to get the IP addresses:

```
dig +short $(grep -Pho '^\s*[^#].*?https?://\K[^/]+(?=.*updates)' \
             /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | sort -u) | sort -u
```

The above will not include any duplicates too.

For the sake of completeness, getting the IP addresses of any configured repository domain,  not just `updates` repositories:

```
dig +short $(grep -Pho '^\s*[^#].*?https?://\K[^/]+' \
             /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | sort -u) | sort -u
```

---

On my system:

```
% dig +short $(grep -Pho '^\s*[^#].*?https?://\K[^/]+' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | sort -u) | sort -u 
123.108.243.101
123.108.243.102
123.108.243.106
123.108.243.110
123.108.243.112
123.108.243.113
123.108.243.117
123.108.243.121
123.108.243.123
123.108.243.80
123.108.243.84
123.108.243.88
123.108.243.90
123.108.243.91
123.108.243.95
123.108.243.99
91.189.88.149
91.189.88.152
91.189.88.161
91.189.88.162
91.189.90.29
91.189.91.23
91.189.91.26

% dig +short $(grep -Pho '^\s*[^#].*?https?://\K[^/]+(?=.*updates)' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list | sort -u) | sort -u
91.189.90.29
```